# ExtJS check if element is visible

Tags: unit-testing, extjs

Does ExtJS provide some quick way to check whether a given component is currently visible? I would normally check css properties like display and visible but what when one of parent elements is hidden?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `Ext.Component.isVisible()`

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.Component.isVisible()
```

Will work if element was hidden by ExtJs functionality.

If parent component will be hidden (e.g. by using jquery's toggle method calling) - this will not work. So in this case I have used such check:

```
var el = $('#real_id'); // Id of the inner element 
if($(el).is (':visible') && $(el).parents (':hidden').length === 0) {
   // The element is 100% visible
}
```

You'll ask why do I need jQuery - the answer is simple: some things can be done more quickly with it... :)